# python scatter plot x axis months instead on many dates

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot that has hourly data of some value on y axis and each hourly data has a corresponding date (24 same dates for a day) as x axis value. When I plot this, the x axis seems too "crowded" and it becomes a black line. I would like to group those dates into months so that I have 12 months (for a year worth of data) on x axis and all the 24h values on the y axis. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9KhK.png) is how the current graph looks like.
And this is my basic plot code:

```
plt.scatter(df['datum'],df['PEF-MFE'])
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

Now, how would I go about grouping the dates so that I get months on the x axis?

Comment: Does this example help? https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

Comment: You need to plot actual dates instead of strings. Possibly just use `df['datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datum'])`, but without [mcve] one cannot tell for sure.